# Eigenvalues of negative companion matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, characteristic-polynomial, companion-matrices

Here's a homework question I've been stuck on for a while.

---

> Given
>
> $$A = \begin{bmatrix}
> 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & a_0 \\
> -1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & a_1 \\
> 0 & -1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & a_2 \\
> \vdots & \vdots & \vdots &\ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
> 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & a_{n-2} \\
> 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & -1 & a_{n-1} \end{bmatrix}$$
>
> Find the characteristic polynomial of $A$ and its eigenvalues.

The characteristic polynomial didn't seem too bad. I calculated a few of them for low values of $n$ and then proved the formula using induction. I think it's:

$$f(\lambda) = a_0 - a_1 \lambda + a_2 \lambda^2 -a_3 \lambda^3 + \cdots + (-1)^{n-1}a_{n-1}\lambda^{n-1} + (-1)^n\lambda^n$$

But then there is the problem of the eigenvalues. This polynomial seems *hopelessly* general in terms of actually finding its roots in terms of the $a_i$s.

Questions:

1. Is the characteristic polynomial correct? I've checked it a few times in hopes of finding something wrong, but I would **love** for this to be the problem. That would make my life a lot easier.
2. If it's correct, how do I find its roots? Is such a thing even possible?

Comment: This is the example provided to show that, given a polynomial, you can always find a matrix with characteristic polynomial equal to the one given. For the eigenvalues the problem is the same as finding all the roots of a given polynomial There is no general way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The problem, as stated, is not solvable (confirmed by the professor who assigned it).**

The characteristic polynomial is correct as written, and there is no general way to find the eigenvalues of this matrix.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** I'm not sure why you need the roots of either polynomial.  Given $f(\lambda) = \lambda^n + a_{n-1}\lambda^{n-1} + \cdots + a_0$, consider $f(-\lambda)$.

In general, something along these lines happens to the characteristic polynomial of a matrix whenever you multiply that matrix by a scalar.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by 'either' polynomial. Only the matrix $A$ was given, and only one characteristic polynomial is associated with it.

Comment: Well, the point is I'm not sure why you're looking for any polynomial roots here.

Comment: The roots of the polynomial are the eigenvalues of the matrix. The question asks for these eigenvalues.

Comment: Ah, okay.  What I meant to say is that you shouldn't find the roots in terms of the $a_i$, find the roots in terms of the roots of the polynomial $\lambda^n + a_{n-1}\lambda^{n-1} + \cdots + a_0$, which are the eigenvalues of the characteristic matrix.